# How long does it usually take to get approved for a Partner account?

Tags: isv, partner

I couldn't find anything on SalesForce or Google that could give me an idea of how long it should take to be approved as an ISV. The closest I found was an estimate of 5-7 business days if you want to be a consultant. The wording I found concerning ISV Partners made it sound like it should be faster than that. It's now been 10 business days. Is this normal?

Comment: I am a little confused why this has been flagged as primarily opinion based. What I want to know is what the average wait time is. That information is a matter of fact, not opinion. I want to comply with the rules, but I don't understand what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The Partner Program is responsible for a lot of things, including reviewing managed packages, helping partners with various problems (patch orgs, fixing licenses, and so on), and, of course, getting back to you in regards to your ISV application. While the program *tries* to get back to everyone within a week, for as long as I've been involved with them, they've had an average response time of closer to 15 business days (three weeks). There's simply not enough of them and too much workload. For now, you'll just need to take the red pill, and go along for the ride. Hold on, Dorothy.

Comment: Thank you. I just needed to know if I should be worried.